# Sublime Text 3 - "jump_forward" command not working

Tags: sublime-text-3

I'm trying to use the jump_back/jump_forward functionality in Sublime Text 3 to navigate between edit locations.

jump_back works as expected with the default key binding (alt+-) but jump_forward does not (with the default key binding or with a custom one).

Is there a way to enable it that I might have missed ?
Can you recommend an alternative to this functionality (plugin or different command) ?

Comment: same here with ST3 on ubuntu 16

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug of sublime on Ubuntu which was reported in 2014 and still has not been fixed (it works on windows):

https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/bug-jump-forward/13356/11